# Kotlin DynamoDB Boolean nullable property never get assigned

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-enhanced-client

I'm writing a test which I need to create a record in local DynamoDB with a nullable boolean property. This is my setup:

```kotlin
@DynamoDbBean
data class Event(
  // other properties
  @get:DynamoDbAttribute("is_enabled")
  var isEnabled: Boolean? = false,
)

companion object {
  val SCHEMA: TableSchema<Event> = TableSchema.fromBean(Event::class.java)
}
```

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient

data class EventRepository(
  private val enhancedClient: DynamoDbEnhancedClient,
) {
  val table: DynamoDbTable<Event> = enhancedClient.table(
        tableNameWithPrefix, Event.SCHEMA)
}
```

```
class TestController  {
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var repo: EventRepository
  
  @Test
  fun test() {
    repo.table.putItem(Event(isEnabled = true))
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how DynamoDB handles boolean values, somehow this field `is_enabled` is always missing in the database. When the property was set to `Boolean?`, the record in database has `is_enabled = null`.

It works if I change the property to Boolean, the record in database has `is_enabled = true when I set the value`.

And changing the property to `Boolean` does not work for me because this value can be nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB does not support nulling of values, it instead has a data type `Null`.

As DynamoDB is a schemaless database, it's suggested not to save Null values.

Furthermore, Java Bean has some guidance on using the `isVariable` naming convention which may also cause issue:  From the JavaBeans specification, 8.3.2:

> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern: public boolean is();
> This is method may be provided instead of a get method, or it may be provided in addition to a get method.

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/

Comment: Thank you!! It works when I change the variable name to `var enable: Boolean? = false`.

Comment: May I ask why this still works? `var isEnable: Boolean = false`

Comment: About the data type `Null`, you mean we shouldn't save the DynamoDB `Null` value right? What is your suggestion for the nullable variable definition? Do you have concerns with this `var enable: Boolean? = false`